# Can i modify HTML DOM of an external URL loaded using window.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, window

Suppose i have a page at : www.mydomain.com

when the user clicks on a button, it opens a new window using :

```
newWin = window.open("https://www.otherdomain.com","a","height=800,width=1000");
```

Now, i want to modify some fields on the page. Specifically, the new window displays a form and i want to be able to autofill the form using the details the user entered on mydomain.com

Is this possible ?

If yes, then that beings me to another question :

Using jQuery, how do i invoke the ready() eventhandler for the newly loaded page ?

EDIT: So, as most guys pointed out here. Its the same origin policy. Can i do it using any other way. Like display the other page in frames ?

Comment: Not possible. Imagine I opened the URL for your favorite bank, but I tweaked it via jQuery so that it posted your login credentials via a Flash object to *my* site, not the bank's.

Comment: Can i do it using any other way. Like display the other page in frames ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont really have much control over the new pages DOM since it is on another domain,

what you do have control over is when u close it:

so lets say u want to close it in 1 minute, on the main window u can do now:

```
setTimout(function(){newWin.close()},60000)
```

but otherwise i dont belive there is much you can do aside from sending javascript calls to the new window by doing:

```
newWin.open('javascript:alert("Hello");');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple of ways :-?

```
newWin = window.open("https://www.otherdomain.com","a","height=800,width=1000");
$(newWin).ready(function(){
    alert('New page has '+newWin.document.forms.length+' forms.');
});
```

Comment: Wait, I just realized it's another domain name. Shrugs.

Comment: This is not going to work, as the browser will enforce the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) due to the difference in domain.

Comment: @Khez so un`-1` me lol. that only works if they are in the same domain lol

Comment: Can i do it using any other way. Like display the other page in frames ?

Comment: Theoretically no. The thing you are trying to do is tantamount to [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Meaning most web browsers will deny javascript from one domain name access to data from another domain name.

Comment: using activeX controls or anything else ? Is there really no way to pre-populate a form for another site from my site ? This can really prove to be the make or break difference for my business :(

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: on my site, the user fills out a form. Depending on the choices he has selected, the appropriate form should open in a new window and the fields which he has filled on my site should autopopulate in the new form. Since the new form is a link to an external URL, I cannot autopopulate the textboxes.

Comment: If the user doesn't need to change the auto-populated fields you can send data directly to the server on the other domain to the corect file with the corect data :-?

Comment: Not possible because the user needs to manually fill in 2-3 fields. The autopopulation just helps the user fill the form quicker.

Comment: @WarDoGG one thing left. browser extensions.